# Is storing XML with a standard structure in SQL Server a bad use of the XML datatype?

Tags: sql-server, xml, database

We have a table in our database that stores XML in one of the columns. The XML is always in the exact same format out of a set of 3 different XML formats which is received via web service responses. We need to look up information in this table (and inside of the XML field) very frequently. Is this a poor use of the XML datatype?

My suggestion is to create seperate tables for each different XML structure as we are only talking about 3 with a growth rate of maybe one new table a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose ultimately this is a matter of preference, but here are some reasons I prefer *not* to store data like that in an XML field:

1. Writing queries against XML in TSQL is slow. Might not be too bad for a small amount of data, but you'll definitely notice it with a decent amount of data.
2. Sometimes there is special logic needed to work with an XML blob. If you store the XML directly in SQL, then you find yourself duplicating that logic all over. I've seen this before at a job where the guy that wrote the XML to a field was long gone and everyone was left wondering how exactly to work with it. Sometimes elements were there, sometimes not, etc.
3. Similar to (2), in my opinion it breaks the purity of the database. In the same way that a lot of people would advise against storing HTML in a field, I would advise against storing raw XML.

But despite these three points ... it can work and TSQL definitely supports queries against it.

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation the supports querying XML in TSQL is slow? That is exactly what I am looking for to support my argument. Thanks Ryan!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270857/are-select-for-xml-querys-slow  Especially note how XML is implemented as a CLR type. Also I'm not sure it's worth it, but my personal experience has been that querying over XML is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the field more than you are writing it?

You want to do the conversion on whichever step you do least often or the step that doesn't involve the user.

Comment: We only write that data one time. So every time we go to read the data we have to look at the XML.